# Track SQL query back to Magento source code

Tags: sql, magento

I'm reviewing slow query log and I've found that below query is inefficient. Given the query how can I trace it back to Magento source code (ideally a file)?:

```
SELECT count(DISTINCT e.entity_id) FROM `sales_flat_order_item` AS `order_items`
 INNER JOIN `sales_flat_order` AS `order` ON `order`.entity_id = order_items.order_id AND `order`.state <> 'canceled' AND (`order`.created_at BETWEEN '2012-08-22 04:17:19' AND '2013-08-22 04:17:19')
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity` AS `e` ON (e.type_id NOT IN ('grouped', 'configurable', 'bundle')) AND e.entity_id = order_items.product_id AND e.entity_type_id = 4
 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `at_visibility_default` ON (`at_visibility_default`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_visibility_default`.`attribute_id` = '102') AND `at_visibility_default`.`store_id` = 0
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `at_visibility` ON (`at_visibility`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_visibility`.`attribute_id` = '102') AND (`at_visibility`.`store_id` = 1)
 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `at_status_default` ON (`at_status_default`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_status_default`.`attribute_id` = '96') AND `at_status_default`.`store_id` = 0
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `at_status` ON (`at_status`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_status`.`attribute_id` = '96') AND (`at_status`.`store_id` = 1) WHERE (parent_item_id IS NULL) AND (IF(at_visibility.value_id > 0, at_visibility.value, at_visibility_default.value) IN(2, 4)) AND (IF(at_status.value_id > 0, at_status.value, at_status_default.value) = '1')\G
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open up `lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php` then you will see as follows:

```
 /**
 * Write SQL debug data to file
 *
 * @var bool
 */
 protected $_debug               = false;  

 /**
 * Log all queries (ignored minimum query duration time)
 *
 * @var bool
 */
 protected $_logAllQueries       = false;

 /**
 * Add to log call stack data (backtrace)
 *
 * @var bool
 */
 protected $_logCallStack        = false;
```

So, if you set `$_logCallStack` to `true` you will see all you need in the log file.