Magento 2.4.6 select query consuming all resource cron jobs
We have a select statement that we cannot trace and keeps being run multiple times
`SELECT `e`.*, IF(at_status.value_id > 0, at_status.value, at_status_default.value) AS `status`, `at_visibility`.`value` AS `visibility` FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e` INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `at_status_default` ON (`at_status_default`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_status_default`.`attribute_id` = '97') AND `at_status_default`.`store_id` = 0 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `at_status` ON (`at_status`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_status`.`attribute_id` = '97') AND (`at_status`.`store_id` = 1) INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `at_visibility` ON (`at_visibility`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_visibility`.`attribute_id` = '99') AND (`at_visibility`.`store_id` = 0) WHERE ((`e`.`updated_at` >= '2024-07-09T10:51:55')) AND ((`e`.`updated_at` < '2024-07-09T12:13:10')) ORDER BY `e`.`updated_at` ASC LIMIT 50`

The difference is the updated at time and they never finish with further instances of each running again and again
Any thoughts on how we trace and stop this from happening?
We have tried rebuilding indexes, disabling cron jobs, truncating DB tables, resetting mview_states and much more

This is a very old answer. But, have you tried this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/18418077/1666143
